# `Extension Development Host` fails with `Cannot find module 'vscode-languageclient' `

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Writing a VSCode Extension which fails with `Cannot find module 'vscode-languageclient'`  in `Extension Development Host` Mode ( `F5` Key ). Not sure how to fix that. If I package the Extension and install the `vsix` File, everything works fine.

Thank's a lot!

[image]

Here is the Output from the `vcse` Tool.

```
D:\Work\Coding\VSCode\Extensions\BDD Recorder\bdd-recorder>vsce ls
Executing prepublish script 'npm run vscode:prepublish'...

> bdd-recorder@0.0.1 vscode:prepublish D:\Work\Coding\VSCode\Extensions\BDD Recorder\bdd-recorder
> npm run compile


> bdd-recorder@0.0.1 compile D:\Work\Coding\VSCode\Extensions\BDD Recorder\bdd-recorder
> tsc -p ./

build_extension.cmd
CHANGELOG.md
out/extension.js
package.json
README.md
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/.eslintignore
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/callHierarchy.proposed.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/client.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/codeConverter.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/colorProvider.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/configuration.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/declaration.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/foldingRange.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/implementation.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/main.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/progress.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/progressPart.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/protocolCodeLens.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/protocolCompletionItem.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/protocolConverter.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/protocolDocumentLink.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/selectionRange.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/semanticTokens.proposed.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/typeDefinition.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/utils/async.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/utils/is.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/utils/processes.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/utils/terminateProcess.sh
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/utils/uuid.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/workspaceFolders.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/License.txt
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/package.json
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/README.md
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/thirdpartynotices.txt
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/node_modules/semver/bin/semver.js
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/node_modules/semver/CHANGELOG.md
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/node_modules/semver/LICENSE
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/node_modules/semver/package.json
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/node_modules/semver/range.bnf
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/node_modules/semver/README.md
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/node_modules/semver/semver.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/.eslintignore
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/main.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/messages.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.callHierarchy.proposed.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.colorProvider.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.configuration.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.declaration.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.foldingRange.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.implementation.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.progress.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.selectionRange.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.sematicTokens.proposed.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.typeDefinition.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/protocol.workspaceFolders.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/lib/utils/is.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/License.txt
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/package.json
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/README.md
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-protocol/thirdpartynotices.txt
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/.eslintignore
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/cancellation.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/events.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/is.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/linkedMap.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/main.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/messageReader.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/messages.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/messageWriter.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/pipeSupport.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/socketSupport.js
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/License.txt
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/package.json
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/README.md
node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/thirdpartynotices.txt
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/.eslintignore
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/lib/esm/main.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/lib/tsconfig.esm.tsbuildInfo
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/lib/umd/main.js
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/License.txt
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/package.json
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/README.md
node_modules/vscode-languageserver-types/tsconfig.esm.json

D:\Work\Coding\VSCode\Extensions\BDD Recorder\bdd-recorder>
```

Answer (score -1):

Changed from `BDD - Feature-Editor 1.1.0` Extension to `Pytest BDD 0.2.5` Extension.